# Subversion Server Side Post Commit Hook

Tags: svn

i have a website with a release history. on every commit the releases.xml should be updated on the www directory.

the post commit hook seems to be client side only. is there a smart way to configure this on the server side, so that also the releases.xml from VPN users gets updated when no SMB share is working? (port might be closed)

i use subversion 1.7, apache 2.x running on debian 6

on sourcesafe there was a feature called "shadow folders". maybe i seek an equiv to that.

and yes i know i should port this to use a database, this is more politics than anything else :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooks (**all** hooks in Subversion) **are server-side** - and repository-wide

Hooks are (properly named according to hook-type) *executable by server OS* program, which have (can) to be placed into hooks subdir in repository directory.

Because hook is ordinary program with predefined set of input parameters, it can perform any actions - it's a question of business-logic and permissions (hooks executed under credentials of user, under which Subversion is running - in your case local user for Apache - and must have rights to read|write for editable file)